# If G is a planar graph with minimum degree 5 then it has at least 12 vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I have no idea how to go about this, other than trying to draw a possible graph and continuing to add vertices until it works. Any help and hints would be so useful - I guess there's a theorem I'm supposed to be using, but can't find a relevant one.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you mean it has *at least* 12 vertices.

Comment: yes - thanks - i've changed it!

Answer (score 6):

Hint: you want to use Euler's formula (vertices minus edges plus faces equals 2), and twice number of edges equals sum of degrees is at least five times number of vertices.

EDIT: One more piece of the puzzle: since every face has as least 3 edges, we get twice the number of edges is at least three times the number of faces. With that, and Euler, you can get that six plus the number of edges is at most three times the number of vertices; then combine that with the edges/vertices inequality to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much - this is incredibly helpful! I've now used Euler's formula to get 2(f-2) less than or equal to 3v. As the graph has minimum degree 5, it must have at least 6 vertices. But I can't figure out how to then prove it needs 12 - how can I get the faces to relate?

Answer (score 2):

Addition to Gerry Myerson's fine answer: The planar graph of |V|=12 with min.degree 5 is a regular graph-- |E|=30 and is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Given a planar graph $G$ of order $n$ and size $m$, $n$ and $m$ must satisfy:

$$
m\le 3n-6.
$$

Since $\delta(G)=5$, we know $m\ge\displaystyle{\frac{5n}{2}}$. Thus

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{5n}{2}\le m&\le 3n-6\\
5n&\le 6n-12\\
-n&\le -12\\
n&\ge 12
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It doesn't say $G$ is 5-regular. Also, you aren't leaving much for OP to do.

Comment: I fixed the error. Should be fine now. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Well-corrected (but second part of comment still applies).

Comment: Meh. This problem is pretty basic. A clear demonstration of how one might use the bound $m\le 3n-6$ is more helpful for future work.

Comment: OP - I am trying to incorporate Gerry Myerson's criticism that I left you nothing to do on this problem (which is correct, I didn't). Using the hints you have received, you might want to consider how Euler's identity can be used to verify the inequality I used in the proof. That might be more illustrative in how these ideas connect.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd actually already proved that in an earlier question, but hadn't noticed the connection.